# How will OAuth be enabled/disabled and how will requests show up in the Google Cloud Console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

As per an email I received from Google, the Google+ APIs will be shut down soon. Currently "Google Sign In" OAuth is represented as a Google+ API when you go to the Google Cloud Console dashboard, and you enable / disable OAuth by enabling / disabling the Google+ API "package" of APIs.

As I understand it, this endpoint is NOT going away:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo

But if the name / concept of Google+ APIs is going away, where will I find our utilization (where will the requests be represented) in the Google Cloud Console, and under what name will the above endpoint be enabled / disabled?